# Google Cloud SSH Server: We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, google-cloud-platform

I am very new to Google Cloud Platform and was trying to restart my VM instance. I entered 
`$ sudo poweroff` into my SSH console, as suggested by https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stopping-or-deleting-an-instance#stop_an_instance
and the console did not return anything. Afterwords I started the VM instance again and the SSH console started returning the message "We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22.".
I have a snapshot of my root disk, but I would really like my instance to be running properly again.

Answer (score 0):

When you run either `sudo poweroff` or `sudo shutdown -h now`, your VM will shutdown right away. This involves flushing any in-memory buffers for disks back to the disks so that you do not lose any unflushed data.

Since you're initiating this command over a `ssh` session, you will not be able to look at any shutdown messages over ssh while the instance is shutting down (since the network service on the VM will also be brought down).

You can use `gcloud compute instances list` or `gcloud compute instances describe VM_NAME` commands to find out the status of the VM.

If it says `RUNNING`, it means the instance is running and you will be able to `ssh` to the VM. If it says `TERMINATED`, it means the instance was shutdown/terminated and you will not be billed for this instance.